# getting "packa ge org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist" error while building a gradle project

Tags: apache, apache-poi

Hi I am using Apache POI in my gradle project. I added all the jar files in classpath. I am using POI version 3.12. I import packages like below

> import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
>   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
>   import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

I am building using ./gradlew command. 
and getting error as below::

> error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist 
>   error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist 
>    error: package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel does not exist

If I include

> compile("org.apache.poi:poi:3.12") 
>       compile("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12")

in build.gradle file, then I am getting following error:

> ←[31mFAILURE: ←[39m←[31mBuild failed with an exception.←[39m
>   * What went wrong:
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
>   ←[33m> ←[39mCould not resolve org.apache.poi:poi:3.12.
>     Required by:
>         project :
>      ←[33m> ←[39mCould not resolve org.apache.poi:poi:3.12.
>         ←[33m> ←[39mCould not get resource 
> 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.12/poi-3.12.pom'.
>            ←[33m> ←[39mCould not GET 
> 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.12/poi-3.12.pom'.
>               ←[33m> ←[39mrepo1.maven.org
>   ←[33m> ←[39mCould not resolve org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12.
>     Required by:
>         project :
>      ←[33m> ←[39mCould not resolve org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12.
>         ←[33m> ←[39mCould not get resource 
> 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.12/poi-ooxml-3.12.pom'.
>            ←[33m> ←[39mCould not GET 
> 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.12/poi-ooxml-3.12.pom'.
>               ←[33m> ←[39mrepo1.maven.org

can anybody please help me to solve this issue and build successfully?
Thank you.

Comment: Errors are pretty clear `Could not resolve` `Could not get resource`  `Could not GET`. So the `HTTP` connection to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi/3.12/poi-3.12.pom fails. Maybe proxy serttings are wrong?

Comment: Also, why are you using an old version of Apache POI?

Comment: I tried using POI version 3.17 also. It was giving me same error. so I tried using version 3.12

Comment: @ Axel Richter Can you please tell me how to check the proxy settings for this POI?

Comment: I am not really familiar with gradle but maybe https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy.

Comment: Thank you. I am going through it. But I was able to build a jar when I did not include POI in the project. Please if somebody can help me here, it will be very helpfull.